# Access ng-model from inside directive link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm attempting to validate inputs inside a directive. Consider the following:

```
.directive('test', function ($parse, $http, $sce, $timeout) {
return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
    },
    template: '<div class="holder">
               <input id="A" name="inputA" ng-model="modelA" />
               <input id="B" name="inputB" ng-model="modelB" />
               </div>',
    link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {
    }
}
```

If I wanted to do my own custom validation inside the link function, how would I reference the "modelA" model? $scope.modelA appears to only reference the value inside the input, not the model itself (which is what I need for validation, as I understand it). All the other references I could find seem to deal with binding referencing models from the parent scope, which I don't need.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you explain more about your problem?  Some sample code inside your link function and html for how you want to use the directive would be nice.

Comment: using `ng-form` on your `holder` class will definitely help. Then validation will be as it would in form tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are using an isolated scope, I can't tell if that's part of your problem, but with an isolated scope and no properties, the parent scope outside the directive will have no way to access the values inside and vice-versa.  I created a plunk to explain isolated scopes: ([***plnkr***](http://plnkr.co/oVVQBxT18BPJmuoWPAGe)).  If you want to access values on your parent scope you probably want something like this for your directive scope:

```
scope: {
    modelA: "=modelA",
    modelB: "=modelB"
},
```

And then calling your directive would work like this:

```
<test model-a="firstName", model-b="lastName"/>
```

Another issue might be that the link function only executes once for each time you use your directive as it is processing it and linking it.  For instance if the value of `modelA` changes then your link function will not be called again.  If you want to do something when `modelA` changes you need to set up a watcher for the change in your link function.  Note that it will be be called once initially without changing the value:

```
link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {
    $scope.$watch('modelA', function(newValue, oldValue) {
         console.log('modelA changed from', oldValue, 'to', 'newValue');
    });
}
```